# Project Euler 138

Tags: c++

**[Problem 138](http://projecteuler.net/problem=138)**

Basically, its asking for isosceles triangles where the height of the triangle is equal to base +- 1. After doing some math on paper, I use either of the following two equations to calculate the length *L* given *b*:

L = sqrt(1.25b<sup>2</sup> + 2b + 1), substituted h with b + 1

or

L = sqrt(1.25b<sup>2</sup> - 2b + 1), substitued h with b - 1

My following code calculates *L* from *b* using both equations. I sum up all the *L* values but it keeps giving me the incorrect answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int result = 0;
  int count = 0;

  for (int b = 1; count < 12; b++) {
    double x;
    double L = std::sqrt(1.25*b*b + 2*b + 1);

    if (std::modf(L, &x) == 0.0) {
      std::cout << count << ": b=" << b << ", L=" << (int)L << "\n";
      result = result + L;
      count++;
    } 

    L = std::sqrt(1.25*b*b - 2*b + 1);
    if (count != 12 && std::modf(L, &x) == 0.0) {
      std::cout << count << ": b=" << b << ", L=" << (int)L << "\n";
      result = result + L;
      count++;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Solution: " << result;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I would like a hint not a solution... I feel like this should be giving me the correct answer.

Comment: @ypercube yeah, the formula isn't correct.

Comment: for an isosceles triangle with height h=b±1 with b the base, the side length satisfies l^2 = (5/4) b^2 ± 2 b + 1. So the formula is correct. But what was to be done from there, I don't understand.

Comment: @ypercube but it is same as  L = sqrt( (b/2)*(b/2) + (b+1)*(b+1) )

Comment: @Walter: You are right, my bad. Removing my comment.

Comment: As evidence that precision is playing a role, your code prints out that `6: b=59907457, L=66978574` is a solution, but b can't be odd if `h = b +/- 1` and `L` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of insufficient numerical precision. I just copied your code and get a different answer depending on whether I use 64-bit (`double`) or 80-bit (`long double`) arithmetic. Of course, the 80-bit answer may still be wrong for the same reason ... you must use exact (integer) arithmetic to be 100% sure (and avoid overflow).